# iOS class like Go channels or good iOS library that simplifies multithreading

Tags: ios, multithreading, locking, queue

I wish to implement background thread that waits for commands from main thread.

like download file from internet or read file from disk or compute something.

There might be 2 queues (channels in Go terms).

from main thread to background thread
from background thread to main thread

I hope there is such example code some where that shows how it must be done in iOS.

I found one solution described in that [tutorial](http://www.cimgf.com/2008/02/16/cocoa-tutorial-nsoperation-and-nsoperationqueue/)
It uses NSOperation and NSOperationQueue

It may solve the problem but not in the way I ask.